# Facebook Error "There was a problem with the parameters of the request. Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Invalid Request"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, title, jwplayer

I am posting a Link to a Webpage with Embedded video tags (youtube, etc..) through the Graph API to a Facebook Group.  This causes the Video to be embedded in the stream but When you click play you get "**There was a problem with the parameters of the request. Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Invalid Request**"

Also this only happens when posting the link through the Graph API

Here is a Link to Show you this Error in action:

http://www.facebook.com/groups/209324852431956

I have created a bug here:  (Please help vote this issue up)
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19191

Here is a Link to a Very Similar Issue:
getsatisfaction.com/sendible/topics/playback_error_in_flash_posts_on_facebook_invalid_request

The solution they used above makes me believe that it is related to the flash player being used.  I am using JW Player, but this also happens with youtube videos posted the same way.. and I have no Idea what player they are using.

It worked when I first started working on my project thesociable.me  then one day it stopped.. and I went through every line of code related to posting links to videos.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had same problem... This alert only show on profile with Timeline activate.
If you post on profile without timeline... swf player does work normally.

I read this link
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/283046815062713?browse=search_4f1e0678a12b73019079378

By the read... the issue is on proccess to solve